# Having trouble adding to postgresql within Django site

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Having to use an older version of Python & Django, I am trying to sync postgresql and this is the error I get. Trying to find origin of the error or other possible methods to try and get this to work, I know it's only the error, but any help is greatly appreciated.

Traceback (most recent call last):ps://www.shubhamdipt.com/blog/django-transfer-data-from-sqlite-to-another-database/

However, when running manage.py loaddata I get this error:

```
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/home/biodem/Biodem/datadump6.json': ContentType matching query does not exist.: (auth.group:pk=None) field_value was '['add_repar to', 'firstpage', 'reparto']'
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/Users/mac/nsa_needtoknow/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 362, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/mac/nsa_needtoknow/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/mac/nsa_needtoknow/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 195, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/mac/nsa_needtoknow/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/mac/nsa_needtoknow/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/Users/mac/nsa_needtoknow/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 100, in handle_noargs
    emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive)
  File "/Users/mac/nsa_needtoknow/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 205, in emit_post_sync_signal
    interactive=interactive)
  File "/Users/mac/nsa_needtoknow/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 166, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/Users/mac/nsa_needtoknow/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/reversion/management/__init__.py", line 45, in create_initial_revisions
    version_save(unversioned_obj)
  File "/Users/mac/nsa_needtoknow/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/reversion/revisions.py", line 326, in _create_on_success
    self.end()
  File "/Users/mac/nsa_needtoknow/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/reversion/revisions.py", line 283, in end
    serialized_data = serializers.serialize(registration_info.format, [obj], fields=registration_info.fields)
  File "/Users/mac/nsa_needtoknow/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 87, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/Users/mac/nsa_needtoknow/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 47, in serialize
    self.handle_fk_field(obj, field)
  File "/Users/mac/nsa_needtoknow/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 48, in handle_fk_field
    related = getattr(obj, field.name)
  File "/Users/mac/nsa_needtoknow/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 257, in __get__
    rel_obj = QuerySet(self.field.rel.to).get(**params)
  File "/Users/mac/nsa_needtoknow/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 306, in get
    % self.model._meta.object_name)
django.contrib.contenttypes.models.DoesNotExist: ContentType matching query does not exist.
```

EDIT: It's Django 1.1.4...

Comment: Start by typing the error message "ContentType matching query does not exist " and "django" into google and reading the various hits including this site?

Comment: Great idea Richard, I never would have thought of that!

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Django > 1.7 try:

```
./manage.py makemigrations  
./manage.py migrate
```

if its an older version of django you need to make sure you have contrib.contenttypes ( I'm not sure which is the first version of Django to come with contenttypes ) then run: ./manage.py syncdb

Comment: Unfortunately it's Django 1.1.4 :(

Comment: I also have the contenttypes in the settings.py, and this was the error received when I ran ./manage.py syncdb, sorry for the little information posted earlier

Comment: hmmm .... it reads "ContentType matching query does not exist" . maybe you are using a contenttype which does not exist in db . try debug and see what is the value of  self.model._meta.object_name